# How do I override the `private` qualifier of a class member in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to use a package `p-queue` which uses `private` to lock one of their members.  Ideally it should be `protected` so developers can extend to add additional functionality.  However, right now I am basically revendoring the component so I can add the functionality I need.

Is there a way of just altering the visibility of a member when extending the class?

Comment: No, `private` cannot be overridden in subclasses; that's the point of it.  Anything you do will be a workaround.  Without a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) it's hard to give concrete examples, though.

Comment: I am looking for a workaround.  Since Javascript itself doesn't have the notion of private.

Comment: Please consider putting code into this question that constitutes a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
const any_this = this as any;
any_this.private_prop = 'is not so private'
```